# How can I get electron branch code use gclient?

Tags: electron-builder

How can I get branch code like electron v3.1.6 and 
Dependency chromium code？

This is about Electron official gived get code.But it's get latest code.

mkdir electron-gn && cd electron-gn
gclient config \
    --name "src/electron" \
    --unmanaged \
    https://github.com/electron/electron
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question properly. It's tagged with `electron-builder`, which is a tool that helps build *applications* with electron, but you seem to be talking about how to build *electron itself* in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `--unmanaged` option makes it so that you can change the remote (repo) and/or branch & `gclient` won't do anything about it. (If I understand correctly.)

from `gclient config --help`:

> --unmanaged           overrides the default behavior to make it possible to
>                           have the main solution untouched by gclient (gclient
>                           will check out unmanaged dependencies but will never
>                           sync them)

Consequently, you can enter the `src/electron` folder and checkout any branch you like. Below is a script that I made for this, based on the [official build instructions](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/pull-requests#setting-up-your-local-environment) (YMMV).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

GN_DIR=${HOME}/tmp/electron-gn
SRC_DIR=$GN_DIR/src
ELECTRON_REPO_URL=https://github.com/user/electron
ELECTRON_REPO_BRANCH=some_branch

# mkdir -p $HOME/tmp
# cd $HOME/tmp
# git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools
DEPOT_TOOLS_DIR=${HOME}/tmp/depot_tools
# Add depot_tools to PATH if not already there (need gclient, gn, ninja, cipd, etc.)
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":${DEPOT_TOOLS_DIR}:"* ]] && export PATH="${PATH}:${DEPOT_TOOLS_DIR}"

export GIT_CACHE_PATH="${HOME}/.git_cache"
export SCCACHE_BUCKET="electronjs-sccache-ci"
export SCCACHE_TWO_TIER=true
export CHROMIUM_BUILDTOOLS_PATH=$SRC_DIR/buildtools
export GN_EXTRA_ARGS="${GN_EXTRA_ARGS} cc_wrapper=\"${SRC_DIR}/electron/external_binaries/sccache\""

echo "Configuring environment with gclient"
cd $GN_DIR
gclient config --name "src/electron" --unmanaged $ELECTRON_REPO_URL
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags

echo "Making sure electron repo is tracking with $ELECTRON_REPO_URL"
cd src/electron
git checkout $ELECTRON_REPO_BRANCH
#git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$ELECTRON_REPO_BRANCH
git pull
cd -

echo "Making sure electron repo is up to date"
cd src/electron
git pull
gclient sync -f
cd -

cd $SRC_DIR
echo "Generating config"
gn gen out/Debug --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/debug.gn\") $GN_EXTRA_ARGS"
echo "Building"
ninja -C out/Debug electron
```